# Error while using LightGraphs to load a graph (xml.gz) in Julia

Tags: julia, lightgraphs

I am trying to load a network in the format xml.gz in Julia by using GraphIO.
The code is the following:

```
using LightGraphs
using GraphIO
D = loadgraphs("test.xml.gz", GraphMLFormat())
```

and I get the following error:

```
┌ Warning: `GraphIO.GraphMLFormat`  has been moved to submodule `GraphIO.GraphML` and needs `EzXML.jl` to be imported first. I.e. use
│     using EzXML
│     GraphIO.GraphML.GraphMLFormat()
│   caller = top-level scope at test.jl:3
└ @ Core ~/File/Code/test_graph/test.jl:3
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: GraphML not defined
```

Then I have tried to import EzXML and do the following:

```
using LightGraphs
using GraphIO
using EzXML
r = GraphIO.GraphML.GraphMLFormat()
D = loadgraphs("test.xml.gz", r)
```

and I get the following error and I do not know how to fix it

```
┌ Warning: `GraphIO.GraphMLFormat`  has been moved to submodule `GraphIO.GraphML` and needs `EzXML.jl` to be imported first. I.e. use
│     using EzXML
│     GraphIO.GraphML.GraphMLFormat()
│   caller = top-level scope at test.jl:5
└ @ Core ~/File/Code/test_graph/test.jl:5
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching bytesavailable(::Inflate.InflateGzipStream)
Closest candidates are:
  bytesavailable(!Matched::Base.SecretBuffer) at secretbuffer.jl:153
  bytesavailable(!Matched::Base.Filesystem.File) at filesystem.jl:198
  bytesavailable(!Matched::Base.BufferStream) at stream.jl:1243
  ...
```

Comment: Some code to generate a simplified version of `"test.xml.gz"` would be usefull

Comment: The graph is a test example, done in python with graph_tool
```
from graph_tool.all import *
import numpy as np
g = random_graph(10**5,lambda: (np.random.poisson(20),np.random.poisson(20)))
g.save('test.xml.gz')
```

Comment: I am actually not sure if zipped files are currently allowed - but consider opening an issue on https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/GraphIO.jl/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with decompression - I can't tell you why but I could also reproduce with other zipped graphs.

Consider unzipping the graph (with gzip on linux for example):

```
gzip -c -d test.xml.gz  > test.xml
```

Then you should be able to load it with

```
D = loadgraph("test.xml", GraphIO.GraphML.GraphMLFormat())
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it, just follow another question's answer on graph I/O